# tax_query (if the terms are empty)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, tax-query

I'm confused, what do I pass in order to get all posts from all terms? Right now I can for instance pass `featured` in order to get all `events`, but how do I get all events? I know I could just get rid of the `tax_query()` however I'm using this as a param, where I can pass along a certain tax or if not, i want all posts.

(what I want, is if there is an event with a tag (featured) that event is shown, if there is no event with the tag (featured), show all events)

```
$now = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$cat = 'featured';
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'events',
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'numberposts' => 4,
'meta_key' => 'start_date',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',
'tax_query' => array(
  array(
      'taxonomy'  => 'events_tag',
      'field'     => 'slug',
      'terms'     => $cat,
      'operator'  => 'IN'
    ),
),
'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'key' => 'start_date',
      'value' => date('Ymd', strtotime('now')),
      'type' => 'numeric',
      'compare' => '>=',
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'end_date',
      'value' => date('Ymd', strtotime('now')),
      'type' => 'numeric',
      'compare' => '>=',
    ),
 ),
if (! is_null($cat))
  'tax_query' => array(
         array(
           'taxonomy'  => 'events_tag',
           'field'     => 'slug',
           'terms'     => $cat,
           'operator'  => 'IN'
        ),
  ),
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by reorganizing your `$args` code to make more sense.

```
$now = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$cat = 'featured';
$args = $cat_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
           'key' => 'start_date',
           'value' => date('Ymd', strtotime('now')),
           'type' => 'numeric',
           'compare' => '>=',
        ),
        array(
           'key' => 'end_date',
           'value' => date('Ymd', strtotime('now')),
           'type' => 'numeric',
           'compare' => '>=',
        ),
    ),
);

// Set the $cat_args array to the category tax_query
$cat_args['tax_query'] = array(
                            array(
                              'taxonomy'  => 'events_tag',
                              'field'     => 'slug',
                              'terms'     => $cat,
                              'operator'  => 'IN'
                            ),
                        );

if ( get_posts( $cat_args ) ) {    // See if any category posts exist
    $query_args = $cat_args;
} else {                           // Otherwise, pass original $args
    $query_args = $args;
}

// Use the newly set $query_args
$wp_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
```

Comment: Thank you, but does not show all events (post), I made a print_r ($ wp_query), and I see that it still shows the tax_query, I do not understand why

Comment: Well, you are setting the `$cat` from the beginning, do you have any posts under that category?

Comment: there is no event with $cat (featured)

Comment: Ok, so I think I understand what you're asking a bit better now.  You want 4 total posts to show up, but you want any featured to show up first, and then pull the number necessary for the remainder?

Comment: what I want, is if there is an event with a tag (featured) that event is shown, if there is no event with the tag (featured), show all events

Comment: I see.  Ok, let me revisit my answer.